# Detecting the end of a overflow-x:scroll element and add a class before animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title suggests I want to detect the start and end of a scrollable element built using overflow.

The following code works:

```
var scrollAmount = 150;
var scrollBox = $('.js-compare_scroll');
var arrowLeft = $('.js-compare_scroll_left');
var arrowRight = $('.js-compare_scroll_right');
var inactive = 'm-inactive';

$(arrowLeft).on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().find(scrollBox).stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: '-='+scrollAmount
    }, function() {
        arrowRight.removeClass(inactive);
        if(scrollBox.scrollLeft() === 0) {
            arrowLeft.addClass(inactive);
        }           
    });
});
$(arrowRight).on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().find(scrollBox).stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: '+='+scrollAmount
    }, function() {
        arrowLeft.removeClass(inactive);
        if(scrollBox.scrollLeft() + scrollBox.innerWidth() >= scrollBox[0].scrollWidth) {
           arrowRight.addClass(inactive);
        }
    });
});
```

However the class to style the inactive colour of the arrows only appears once the animation completes. I need to add the class before the animation completes because it has a delay. I believe by default it is 400.

Is there anyway to detect this and apply the arrow classes where needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Came back from a break and realised I should take the checking if its at the end off the click event and onto a scroll event. This works a lot better now.